# Android.How to get details about Location Updates in android?

Tags: android

I am building application in which i am using Google Maps. I am using code to request location update every 10 meter or 15 seconds.But i want to know is there any way i can know the distance between last location update and latest location update if the provider does not able to provide update for some time.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 15000, 10, this);


    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {

        onLocationChanged(location);
        if (provider.matches("gps")) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need to calculate the distance between 2 lat/lng points, the previous one (you could store in a global variable, or even save it in the SharedPreferences) and the new one (that you just get in onLocationChanged event)

The code below is an example I used in a project, I hope it helps!

```
String distance = "";
float distanceSort = 0;

float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(currentlatLnglatitude, currentlatLnglongitude,
        oldlatitude, oldlongitude, results);

if (results.length > 0)
{
    distanceSort = results[0];
    if (distanceSort < 1000)
    {
        int roundedDistance = Math.round(distanceSort);
        distance = String.valueOf(roundedDistance) + " m";
    }
    else
    {
        int roundedDistance = Math.round(distanceSort / 1000);
        if (roundedDistance > 50)
        {
            distance = "> 50 km";
        }
        else
        {
            distance = String.valueOf(roundedDistance) + " km";
        }
    }

}
```